# How do I remove duplicate arrays inside an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

How do I remove duplicate sorted arrays in Javascript?
I have tried making a new array, using spread syntax on a new set, but that looks extremely complicated, and forced my result set to look like this:

```
[ [ '-', '1', ',', '0', ',', '1' ],
  [ '-', '1', ',', '-', '1', ',', '2' ] ]
[ [ '-', '1', ',', '0', ',', '1' ],
  [ '-', '1', ',', '-', '1', ',', '2' ] ]
[ [ '0', ',', '0', ',', '0' ] ]
[ [ '0', ',', '0', ',', '0' ] ]
[ [ '-', '4', ',', '-', '2', ',', '6' ],
  [ '-', '4', ',', '0', ',', '4' ],
  [ '-', '4', ',', '1', ',', '3' ],
  [ '-', '4', ',', '2', ',', '2' ],
  [ '-', '2', ',', '-', '2', ',', '4' ],
  [ '-', '2', ',', '0', ',', '2' ] ]
[ [ '-', '4', ',', '-', '2', ',', '6' ],
  [ '-', '4', ',', '0', ',', '4' ],
  [ '-', '4', ',', '1', ',', '3' ],
  [ '-', '4', ',', '2', ',', '2' ],
  [ '-', '2', ',', '-', '2', ',', '4' ],
  [ '-', '2', ',', '0', ',', '2' ] ]
```

or

```
[ [ '-1,0,1' ], [ '-1,-1,2' ] ]
[ [ '-1,0,1' ], [ '-1,-1,2' ] ]
[ [ '0,0,0' ] ]
[ [ '0,0,0' ] ]
[ [ '-4,-2,6' ],
  [ '-4,0,4' ],
  [ '-4,1,3' ],
  [ '-4,2,2' ],
  [ '-2,-2,4' ],
  [ '-2,0,2' ] ]
[ [ '-4,-2,6' ],
  [ '-4,0,4' ],
  [ '-4,1,3' ],
  [ '-4,2,2' ],
  [ '-2,-2,4' ],
  [ '-2,0,2' ] ]
```

mind you, these are after I set them to strings. 
The set will not remove duplicate sorted arrays since they are different objects.

Here is the code.

```
var threeSum = function (arr) {
    let map = new Map();
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let num = arr[i];
        if (map.has(num)) {
            map.get(num).push(i);
        }
        else {
            map.set(num, [i]);
        }
    }

    const results = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            let diff = (arr[i] + arr[j]);
            diff = (diff == 0) ? diff: diff * -1;
            if (map.has(diff)) {
                let mArr = map.get(diff);
                for (let k = 0; k < mArr.length; k++) {
                    if (mArr[k] != i && mArr[k] != j ) {
                        results.push([arr[i], arr[j], diff]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    results.forEach((value) => {
        value.sort((a, b) => { return a - b });
    });
    let newResults = results.filter((val, idx, arr) => {
        /// how do i do this
    })

    console.log(newResults);
    return newResults;

}

console.log(threeSum([-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4]));
console.log(threeSum([0,0,0,0]));
console.log(threeSum([-4,-2,-2,-2,0,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,6,6]));
```

Comment: So long as they are sorted you can stringify  the array  using JSON.stringify or join()  and pass to Set or Map as string keys

Comment: What is format of expected output?

Comment: Expected:
[[-4,-2,6],[-4,0,4],[-4,1,3],[-4,2,2],[-2,-2,4],[-2,0,2]]

Comment: And what is the input for that?

Comment: Input:
[-4,-2,-2,-2,0,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,6,6]

Comment: ok...not clear what chunking rules are then to get expected results from that input

Comment: LMAO 

Given an array nums of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in nums such that a + b + c = 0? Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.

Note:

The solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **[set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)** is perfect for this task. Sets maintain the condition that all of its elements are unique. This is how you can accomplish your task:

1. Create a new set containing the elements of results: `let set = new Set(results.map(result => JSON.stringify(result))`
2. Convert the set into an array. This can be done using `Array.from(set).map(elem => JSON.parse(elem))`

Comment: Need to stringify arrays for them to be unique in a set. `[1,2] != [1,2]`... try `console.log(new Set([[1,2], [1,2]])) // size=2 `

Comment: Yep, that gave me the exact same array

Comment: Apologies, I had completely forgotten that. How you can correct my error is by `.map`ing the results to strings before inserting them into the set, and then `.map`ing them back to arrays when you pull them from the set. I have editted my answer to reflect this.

Comment: And also must be sorted first before stringifying them

Comment: `.sort` can be called after converting the set to an error and before mapping the string back to an array.

Comment: Ahh but if results were `[[1,2],[2,1]]` and OP wants unique sorted arrays...those would stringify to 2 set values unsorted

Comment: Darn it, I knew I was missing something. While mapping the output, you could sort before stringifying `JSON.stringify(result.sort())` then sort the mapped output too.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some other problems in the formation of `results`, but to simply get unique items from sorted array:

Define a function to check arrays `a` and `b` are equal for first `L` indexes (since `a == b` by itself does not work):

```
let equal = function(a, b, L){
    for (let i=0; i<L; ++i) {
        if (a[i] != b[i]) return false; 
    }
    return true;
}
```

Push to `newResults` when new item is detected.

```
var threeSum(...
...
    if (results.length == 0){
        return [];
    }
    newResults = [results[0]];

    for (let i = 1; i < results.length; ++i){
        if (!equal(results[i], newResults[newResults.length - 1], 3)){
            newResults.push(results[i]);
        }
    }

    return newResults;
}
```

But there may be some other problems, such as iterating through all items of `map.get(diff)` although the first item `mArr[0]` is the key (and the rest are values)